# Open any files (.doc, .xls,. pdf. etc.) with related program saved in sql server as varbinary?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Is there any way, Open any files (.doc, .xls,. pdf. etc.) with related program saved in sql server as varbinary ?

Creating Database in server;

```
create database DEV
GO
USE DEV
GO
create Table FileWarehouse
(
Id int identity (1,1),
FileType Nvarchar (50),
StoredFile Varbinary (MAX)
)
```

I am storing the files in database as it is shown;

```
insert into FileWarehouse
select 'docx' as FileType,*
from OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\SQLDOC\WILLBESAVEDINSERVER.docx', SINGLE_BLOB)
AS X
```

I can get file from server and saved to a folder as it is shown;

```
DECLARE 
@SQLIMG VARCHAR (MAX),  
@File VARBINARY (MAX),
@OutputPath VARCHAR (MAX),
@ObjectToken INT

Select @File = StoredFile FROM FileWarehouse where FileType ='docx' -- or use id
SET @OutputPath = 'C:\SQLDOC\OUTPUT\output_word_fromServer.docx'
EXEC sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @ObjectToken OUTPUT
EXEC sp_OASetProperty @ObjectToken, 'Type',1
EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Open'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Write', NULL, @File
EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'SaveToFile', NULL, @OutputPath,2
EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Close'
EXEC sp_OADestroy @ObjectToken
GO
```

But I cannot open the file directly from database; Using codes as below;

```
  private void btnOpenDocument_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = (int)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["ID"].Value;


        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adp.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("GetDocument");
        adp.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        adp.SelectCommand.Connection = ResimGaleri.ORM.Tools.Baglanti;
        adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = sd.ID;

        // add here extension that depends on your file type
        string fileName = Path.GetRandomFileName() + ".txt";

        using (SqlConnection conn = ResimGaleri.ORM.Tools.Baglanti)
        {
            ResimGaleri.ORM.Tools.Baglanti.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = adp.SelectCommand)
            {
                // you have to distinguish here which document, I assume that there is an `id` column


                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        int size = 1024 * 1024;
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                        int readBytes = 0;
                        int index = 0;

                        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                        {
                            while ((readBytes = (int)dr.GetBytes(0, index, buffer, 0, size)) > 0)
                            {

                                fs.Write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                                index += readBytes;

                            }


                        }

                    }



                }

            }
        }

        // open your file, the proper application will be executed because of proper file extension
        ResimGaleri.ORM.Tools.Baglanti.Close();
        Process prc = new Process();
        prc.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
        prc.Start();

    }
}
```

Comment: so I can insert a virus into this column in your database and than using sql server execute it on your database server. I am not sure if sql server even allows this but I hope not

Comment: How can you insert a virus into and which column ? Interesting.

Comment: I guess there will be some client that allows this table to be filled ?

Comment: If you will use this program only would you do that. If not is there any way not to allow ? Thanks for the warning.

Comment: If you have acces to the database, say sql managment studio, than you can insert into the table whatever you want. But you need access to the database offcourse. The program will have this I guess

Comment: You clearly have not finished code based on comment about extension. Please review you code and make sure all parts are finished to the best of your knowledge. Than [edit] post to provide just necessary code -  see [mcve] for guidance.

Comment: You can avoid all the trouble by using SQL Server's [FILESTREAM](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993(v=sql.105).aspx) storage which stores the files as ... files and returns a path to them that a client application can use to read them

Comment: Should I understand you wont suggest me to store any files as varbinary file in the database. Should I store them in a desired folder instead?

Comment: And why are you opening the document on the _server_?  Seems more reasonable top send the file to the client and let _them_ open it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see in your code is that you save a file "someRandomName".txt.

So when you call Process.Start, Notepad (or whatever else is the default program for txt files) will be launched.

You need to save in the db also the original file name (or at least, the original extension, which you already do if I'm not wrong), so you can create a (temporary?) file "someRandomName".OriginalExtension

```
string fileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetRandomFileName(), dr.GetString("FileType");
```

As @GuidoG says, be sure all files saved on db are safe!

Comment: I have also added the extension and the file name in another table.

Comment: so use it to save your (temporary?) file!

Comment: temp file has been created but won't opened somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, I would have save the file in a temporary location first.
Then open the file with the options we have in `System.Diagnostics`. Like that:

```
Process.Start(fileName);
```

Or, you can use `ProcessStartInfo` for more options:

```
ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(fileName);
processInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
Process.Start(processInfo);
```

Comment: temp file has been created but won't opened somehow.

Comment: Have you got any message? Exception? Can you open it manually?